# SSIS Script Task Debugging When Checking Value Comparison

Tags: variables, ssis, runtime-error, dts

I have this code in a script task:

```
Public Sub Main()
    '
    ' Add your code here
    '
    Dim MonthFromSQL As String
    Dim lastMonth As New Date(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month - 1, 1)
    Dim rcnt As Integer
    Dim msg As String
    'MsgBox("Month name from SQL is " & CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value))
    rcnt = CInt(Dts.Variables("RowCount").Value)
    If rcnt = 0 Then
            msg = "Job returned 0 rows for month " & CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) & " - check with database operator that previous month's data has been loaded into the database."
     Else
            msg = "Job returned " & rcnt & " rows - Job Finished"
     End If
    'Pass message variable value out to be used in message 
    Dts.Variables("EmailMessage").Value = msg
    Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success
End Sub
```

If I modify the IF statement to below to be able to check the month value from SQL DB against system month value it gives me a DTS script error saying that:

> The type of the value being assigned to variable "User::EmailMessage" differs from the current variable type. Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.

```
'First check month name from sql match system last month name
    If CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) = CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value) Then
        MsgBox("Month name variable equals last month value")
        If rcnt = 0 Then
            msg = "Job returned 0 rows for month " & CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) & " - check with outpatient database operator that previous month's data has been loaded into the database."
        Else
            msg = "Job returned " & rcnt & " rows - Job Finished"
        End If
    Else
    'Put in code to handle if month values do not match
    End If
```

I replaced:

```
If CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) = CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value) Then
        MsgBox("Month name variable equals last month value")
```

With:

```
If 1=1 Then
MsgBox("Month name variable equals last month value")
```

Just to check it would work with a simple comparing statement and that it was something to do with the code I had in the IF statement, as I did not suspect it was anything to do with the msg variable I was populating, even though this was the error message.

So I realise it is something to do with:

```
If CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) = CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value) Then
```

The montNameFromSQL is populated with the result set of a previous SQL task, and then in this script I am using it to check against the system month name. I want to check these values and if a match then success and move onto to check the rows returned, and populate the message to send in my email task.

Hopefully it's something simple and a fresh pair of eyes can spot!

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: what is the data type of Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value? is it object type? Also show sql script which used in the sql task for populating the montNameFromSQL variable.

Comment: No data type is string rather than object. The query below is used to get the value of monthName (the alias in query) into MonthNameFromSQL using result set property in sql task
:select distinct convert(varchar(12),(datename(month, date_column)))  as monthName
  FROM dbo.table1

Comment: After changing the statement to If 1=1 Then MsgBox("Month name variable equals last month value"),  was the error remained the same?

Comment: No it worked fine, as in it went through the code and never fell over.

Comment: only issue i see is with the data type of MonthNameFromSQL variable. when you uncommented this line, 'MsgBox("Month name from SQL is " & CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value)). do you see expected value?.

Comment: No it fell over before this message came up

Answer (score 0):

Either you have the wrong data types assigned (which is what the error message is stating) or you have not faithfully reproduced your code.

I created a package with 3 variables.

- EmailMessage: String -
- MonthNameFromSQL: String - July
- RowCount: Int32 - 0

[image: Control flow]

I configured my "SCR Works fine" task to allow read access to the second two variables and read/write access to EmailMessage.

[image: VB is icky]

Inside the script, I used your code. I ran it with your original that works and the one that doesn't work for you.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim MonthFromSQL As String
    Dim lastMonth As New Date(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month - 1, 1)
    Dim rcnt As Integer
    Dim msg As String

    'MsgBox("Month name from SQL is " & CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value))
    rcnt = CInt(Dts.Variables("RowCount").Value)
    'If rcnt = 0 Then
    '    msg = "Job returned 0 rows for month " & CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) & " - check with database operator that previous month's data has been loaded into the database."
    'Else
    '    msg = "Job returned " & rcnt & " rows - Job Finished"
    'End If

    'First check month name from sql match system last month name
    If CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) = CStr(Dts.Variables("MonthNameFromSQL").Value) Then
        MsgBox("Month name variable equals last month value")
        If rcnt = 0 Then
            msg = "Job returned 0 rows for month " & CStr(MonthName(lastMonth.Month, False)) & " - check with outpatient database operator that previous month's data has been loaded into the database."
        Else
            msg = "Job returned " & rcnt & " rows - Job Finished"
        End If
    Else
        'Put in code to handle if month values do not match
        msg = "I am here"
    End If

    'Pass message variable value out to be used in message 
    Dts.Variables("EmailMessage").Value = msg

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

As you can see from the value of the EmailMessage variable, it's populated and the script has completed.

[image]

This package is using SQL Server 2012 but the fundamentals of what you are trying has been available since 2005.

- [Integration Services (SSIS) Variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141085.aspx)
- [Using Variables in the Script Task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx)

Comment: appreciate you trying that out for me. I will look back through my set up again at some point today, hopefully before I lose my morning "fresh eyes"!

Comment: found that my msg variable is empty even though my row count has a value and it should populate the msg variable with message in the IF statement. So it's falling over because I am trying to put nothing into the package variable EmailMessage via my script variable msg

Answer (score 0):

only issue I see is with the data type of MonthNameFromSQL variable, somehow MonthNameFromSQL is assigned wrong data type or its getting null value.

I will recommend you to do the following.

1. Ensure that date_column datetime field in your table is NOT NULLABLE or Do null check in your sql statement to ensure that it is not passing any null values to the MonthNameFromSQL variable.

   select distinct ISNULL(convert(varchar(12),(datename(month, date_column))), '') as monthName FROM dbo.table1
2. Delete the MonthNameFromSQL varialble from variablbe window(shown on
       the left pane in visual studio), recreate this variable again
       ensuring that scope of the variable is at package level and data
       type is string type. select this variable from result set of execute
       sql task properties.
3. If above step fails, recreate package freshly.

Comment: S.M thanks for the advice will try and get a look into this today again.